# Saving items fetched from API into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently fetching 10 items ([REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)) from this external API in the background ([DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record)). But how do I save them to the database when they're done loading?

**main_controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Delay fetching
    @products = Affiliate.delay.fetch
  end
end
```

**affiliate.rb**

```
require "rest_client"

class Affiliate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :get,
      :url => "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&fts=women&offset=0&limit=10"
    )

    @products = JSON.parse(response)["products"].map do |product|
      product = OpenStruct.new(product)
      product
    end

    # CODE TO INSERT INTO DB GOES HERE?
    # THIS MAYBE? @products.save!
  end
end
```

**20150604213141_add_items_to_affiliates.rb**

```
class AddItemsToAffiliates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:affiliates) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little confused by your question, but if you're asking how to map data from your `product` to `affiliate`, we'd need to know more about the data in both...

But in general, to save attributes in Rails data is simply:

```
model_instance = Model.new #or model = Model.find(id) #or model = Model.where("conditions")
model_instance.attribute_name = new_attribute_value
mdoel_instance.save
```

So in your case, you would either find or create a new affiliate by mapping the data from your `products` loop to `affiliate`.

Something like this:

```
products = JSON.parse(response)["products"].map do |product|
  product = OpenStruct.new(product)
  affiliate = Affiliate.find_or_create_by_name_and_url(:name => product.name, :url => product.url)
  #or
  affiliate = Affiliate.new #or Affiliate.create(:name => product.name, :url => product.url)
  affiliate.save
end
```

There are a whole bunch of different ways to handle `active_record` searching / updating. [The guide is a good resource for the basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Comment: Greetings! Any idea where I went wrong? Saving seems okay, I just can't seem to display the items in the view: https://gist.github.com/dt1973/ecebdb2bdd36d4cd2b3a

Comment: Just commented on your gist. Are you saving the data to the db correctly?

Comment: `.fetch` isn't a valid activerecord query. `.all` returns all of them. You could also do a `.where()` with a set of conditions in that case.

Comment: But isn't it supposed to launch the `def self.fetch` method? Will `.all` launch all methods in that class? Like, what will happen if I have other methods there as well, say for properly sorting the JSON response etc.?

Comment: I don't think there is an ActiveRecord::Base `self.fetch` method (or at least I couldn't find one). `.all` is a ActiveRecord::Base class method which returns an array of activerecord objects by calling `SELECT * FROM model_name`.  That's all it does, from there you iterate through your records to manipulate, show or change the instances as you see fit. That link in my answer is a great resource for ActiveRecord basics and those are the underpinnings of Rails CRUD behavior

Comment: if you were to call `.where` it's the same thing except it applies a where clause to your query. Either way, when you get your returned array, you can sort or iterate through them. If you want to sort on your query, you can do so with a chained call `Affiliate.all.order(:id)` or `Affiliate.all.order(:created_at)`. More info on [querying here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)